# Our GCP docker instance is up and running but then we are unable to connect to the GreenPlum

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, greenplum

Our GCP docker instance is up and running but we are unable to connect to the GreenPlum  and it is giving the *Connection to xx.xxx.xxx.xx:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.   Connection refused (Connection refused)*

We are facing the issue while connecting to the Greenplum Database which is hosted on the docker container of GCP.
The following steps have been followed but none of them works:

1. Restarted the docker instance

While restarting the Greenplum i tried
`sudo docker exec -it gp_v1 /bin/bash -c 'sudo su - gpadmin -c ". /opt/greenplum-db-6.4.0/greenplum_path.sh ; gpstart -a"'`

It gives

`[ERROR]:- FATAL - no master dbs defined!`

`[CRITICAL] :- gpstart failed. (Reason='Error: GpArray() - no master dbs defined') exiting....`

Could anyone please help me with this, it is critical and our Greenplum is down for the past 10 hours.

I also suspect that the port 5432 is not working and it is showing closed when I check on this website https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to a closed port?

Comment: Actually I am trying to open that 5432 port, but I can't find how to do it. I have tried few other posts which helps to change port number but nothing working.

Comment: Goto firewall configuration, create a rule for that and then label the external network interface with it... also in the `Dockerfile` you'd likely need to `EXPOSE 5432`.

Comment: Why are you using Docker for this? Just use the Greenplum GCP Marketplace listing.

Answer (score 0):

As the user [Martin Zeitler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549372/martin-zeitler) suggested, you have to go to Firewall configuration and create a rule for that port. In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) you can a VPC firewall rules overview.

Also, add in your **Dockerfile** `EXPOSE 5432`.